# Is variable scope causing my function to malcfunction?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm preety basic at this but I believe I know what's wrong with my code.

```
$consulta_img = "SELECT `poster`, `screenshot1`, `screenshot2`, `screenshot3`, `screenshot4`, `screenshot5`, `screenshot6`, `screenshot7`, `screenshot8` FROM `serie` WHERE `id`='$_POST[id_editar]'";
$imagenes = mysql_query ($consulta_img);
$imagen = mysql_fetch_array($imagenes);


function actualizar_imagen($imagen_cargada){
    if($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'] != ""){
        $imagen_actual = $imagen[$imagen_cargada];
        unlink("../publico/img/".$imagen_actual);
        $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
        $imagen_final = $fecha . $_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['tmp_name'], '../publico/img/' . $imagen_final);
    }
    return $imagen_final;
}
```

I supose the mistake is here: `$imagen_actual = $imagen[$imagen_cargada];` where trying to call `$imagen[$imagen_cargada];` inside the function is not working. If so, how can I fix it?

This is the error I'm getting back:

```
Warning: unlink(../publico/img/) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\AppServ\www\dejavu\administrador\editar.php on line 18
```

Line 18 is the unlink().

BTW, I know mysql is deprecated but that's not my concern right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already pointed out the problem. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) suggests one solution: Declaring `$imagen` global inside the function:

```
function actualizar_imagen($imagen_cargada){
    global $imagen;
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have the required permission for your `/publico/img` directory. Do a **`chmod 777`** on the `public` directory and try the same code as this is definitely related to permission problems.